Remesh not adding more resolution?
after using dyntopo I wanted to remesh and add more faces overall. But remesh doesnt do anything?
Heres what I mean



https://drive.google.com/file/d/11tpv2yXdx5oPBiGF9uwxJDqeicVYrELx/view?usp=sharing
Heres the file incase it helps, i deleted other unnecessary meshes in file but its still big, apologies!
If you ahve any ideas how else I could make it smaller please teach me thank you!

Are you actually pressing Ctrl+R to remesh it or are you just pressing Shift+R to enable the "Set Resolution" modal? Those numbers just mean you're setting how big the remesh voxels will be but it doesn't actually run the operator until you press Ctrl+R

You absolute god, thank you!
Jeez laweez i cant believe i just wasnt pressing it thanks so much man!!XD
